# Path connected subset $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

We all know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is path connected. Consider the subset $S=\{(x,y):\mid \mid (x,y)\mid \mid \geq c, \text{for fixed $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$}\}.$ It can be geometrically visualize that $S$ is path connected.

But I need a precise path between any two points of $S$. I think the path should be circular, but I do not know that how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the points are given by $x=r_1 e^{i\theta_1},y=r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$. Then a path can  be given by 
$$\gamma(t)=((1-t)r_1+tr_2)e^{i((1-t)\theta_1+t\theta_2)}$$ 
for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: please have a look on th question again, I have edited it. One more question, why this $\gamma$ will lie in $S$?

Comment: If $x,y$ are in $S$, then $r_1,r_2\geq c$. Then the norm of $\gamma(t)$ is $\geq\min\{r_1,r_2\}\geq c$, so it lies in $S$.

Comment: I think same map will work for the edited $S$. How it can be seen that $\mid \mid \gamma(t)\mid \mid>\text{min}\{r_1,r_2 \}$.

Comment: The norm of $\gamma(t)$ is $(1-t)r_1+tr_2$, and $r_1,r_2$ are $\geq \min\{r_1,r_2\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Peter +1. I didn't know this argument. In $\mathbb R^{n}$ path connectedness of $\{x:\|x\|>c\}$ is not that easy right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think one only needs to consider the plane induced by $x,y$ and use the similar arguments.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. My question was silly.